# Receive data from weighing scale CAS CL5200

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

Need help with CAS CL5200 scale.
i have already seen all the posts regarding this problem , but none of them are working regarding CAS CL5200 scale- connected with USB cable that creates a virtual com port (COM41)

here are the steps i followed -

1. To test the communication, I installed CL-Works (scales software for some functions) --> working.
2. Installed Free Device Monitoring Studio to see all the connection params.
3. Tested with hyperterminal --> not working
4. Free Device Monitoring Studio reports that "W" is written to com port but nothing returns.
5. The code here is what I found on other related post, tested it with byte[] and string, either way the code writes on COM41 "W" but there is nothing to read.

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int BaudRate = 19200; // BaudRate Constant

    private SerialPort _serialPort;

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
        if (_serialPort != null)
            _serialPort.Dispose();

        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM41", BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); // Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        // _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived; // this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        _serialPort.Open();

        textBox1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...\r\n";

       // byte[] towrite = GetBytes("W"); // get the weight from scale wiyh "W" as byte[]
       // _serialPort.Write(towrite,0,1);
        _serialPort.WriteLine("W");
    }

    private delegate void Closure();
    void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired) // makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
            BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { _serialPort_DataReceived(sender, e); })); //<-- Function invokes itself
        else
            while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
            {
                //textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());
                textBox1.Text += _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                //<-- bytewise adds inbuffer to textbox
            }
    }

    private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Further test show that the events DataReceived and ErrorReceived does not fire ....

Comment: anyone ... some ideas ?

Comment: With the serial listener, I managed to view and communicate with the scale with some commands like "R88A" (this command reads the plu table), but in the weight reading direction, nothing yet. I hope someone reached further.

Comment: I did it. The command to request weight is "R45F04,00" send as string receive something like "W45F04,000L00D:W=00017E.w=3.`" where W is the weight in hexa.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the data in the hyperterminal, you can't see it in the code you wrote. See it there first. then try this

```
   private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Get_Data(serialPort1.ReadLine().ToString());
    }
    private void Get_Data(string Result_Data)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (!InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                double dNew = Convert.ToDouble(Result_Data) / 100;
                lbl_weight.Text = dNew.ToString("N2");
              
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }
        }
        else { Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Get_Data(Result_Data))); }
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    public void Connection_Start()
    {


            string comport = "COM1";
            serialPort1.DataReceived += new 
            SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
            serialPort1.PortName = comport;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Open();
        

    }
```